# Change the color and icon of the gear of shinydashboard dashboardControlBar

Tags: r, shinydashboard

How can someone change the color and icon of the gear of shinydashboard dashboardControlBar?

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(
      #tags$style(".fa-thumbtack {color:rgb(255,0,0)}"), ##  this changes only the horizontal pin color
      tags$head(tags$style(type = "text/css", ".fa-thumbtack {color:rgb(255,0,0)  !important;}"))
    ),
    controlbar = dashboardControlbar(
      id = "controlbar",
      collapsed = FALSE,
      overlay = TRUE, 
      skin = "light",
      pinned = T
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To change the color use `skin =` where you can set various colors: see here https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/appearance.html
2. To change the icon of the former known "right-sidebar" now known as "controlbar" use `controlbarIcon` in `dashboardHeader`: Here we changed the gear icon with the info icon:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(skin = "purple",
    options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE),
    header = dashboardHeader(
      controlbarIcon = shiny::icon("info")
    ),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(
      #tags$style(".fa-thumbtack {color:rgb(255,0,0)}"), ##  this changes only the horizontal pin color
      tags$head(tags$style(type = "text/css", ".fa-thumbtack {color:rgb(255,0,0)  !important;}"))
    ),
    controlbar = dashboardControlbar(
      id = "controlbar",
      collapsed = FALSE,
      overlay = TRUE, 
      skin = "light",
      pinned = T
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
  }
)
```

[image]